# How to load an element to jQuery if all i have is an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to make a jQuery variable if the id is empty. I have been using the code below but when the element that is clicked on has no ID is causes an error as the string that I am trying to create the variable from will only be '#'

```
$('body').on('click touch', function (evt) {
    if ($('#' + evt.target.id).parents().hasClass('popper'))
        alert("Parent contains class");
});
```

Comment: You don't need the id.  `evt.target` **is** the element...  Just stick `$(evt.target)` and use it

Comment: In that case, `evt.target` is `body`, is it really what you want to target? You should add the event listener on the related element.

Comment: @Zysce i'd have to double check it, but if the event originated from a child that bubbled up to the body, i believe the evt.target will be the child element.  While `this` will always be the body, in this case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ebdam3z9/ @Zysce

Comment: Ok, my bad, at least I learned smtg :)

Comment: You guys are awesome. Pretty sure its this: "You don't need the id. evt.target is the element... Just stick $(evt.target) and use it "

Comment: Also, sorta an aside note, but if you are only concerned with the children of elements that belong to '.popper' elements, then you could add that to your original selector to narrow down the scope of your event handler, provided they are not dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the clicked element in `evt.target`, so it doesn't need to have an id at all -- just wrap it in jQuery and continue on your way:

```js
$('body').on('click touch', function(evt) {
  if ($(evt.target).parents().hasClass('popper'))
    alert("Parent contains class");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>No class - no id</button>
  <button id="stuff">No class - has id</button>
</div>
<div class="popper">
  <button>Has class - no id</button>
  <button id="things">Has class - has id</button>
</div>
```